# links are showing up on each line, instead of inline

Tags: html, css

On a blog detail page, I have a tags section.

The html looks like:

```
<td class="tags">
<a href="">tag1></a>, <a href="">tag2</a>
</td>
```

For some reason the tags are showing up, each on their own line, instead of being inline.

I know I can create a new style to fix this, I just have to make sure the CSS style is specific enough to target this section.

But how can I force them on the same line?

I tried:

```
display:inline
```

but that didn't work.

The css:

```
.entry .entry_meta_bottom a,
.entry_individual .entry_meta_bottom a {
    display: block;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    line-height: 1.75em;
    background-position: 0 60%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-right: 10px; 
}
.entry .entry_meta_bottom td.tags,
.entry_individual .entry_meta_bottom td.tags 
{       
    background-image:url("../icon_tags.gif");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding:0 0 0 25px; 

}
```

Comment: Do you have any other styles for the default 'a' class? Also, what styles do you have for the 'tags' class?

Comment: We'd have to see more of your code. Or, since this is a table cell, it could be that the column is too narrow and you're just getting a wrapping effect. Try widening the table and seeing if that helps.

Comment: added the CSS to the question above.

Comment: in firebug, I can see the containing element is much much wider than the table, so I set the table to 100%, but the links are all still on their own line.

Comment: Post your html too. You have .entry this and that but we can't see the html with .entry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trying to set `display: inline` is the right idea. My supposition is that you didn't make your selector specific enough to override the `display: block` set in `.entry .entry_meta_bottom a, .entry_individual .entry_meta_bottom a`.

Try the following:

```
.entry .entry_meta_bottom td.tags a,
.entry_individual .entry_meta_bottom td.tags a {
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: yup that was it, specificity ones again!

Comment: I have had to learn a lot of hard lessons about specificity through trial and error. I'm glad to be able to share what I've learned on a site like this :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the `td` is wide enough to contain both tags side-by-side? Table cells wrap their contents by default (it's one of the reasons people like them).

Comment: Well the content above (blog text) is visible and its wider than the tag list.  I added width=500 to the table and no difference, actually it just shifted the tags section to the right but they are still on their own line.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, the issue is almost certainly due to the width of the `td` element, but if you want to force it to not break you could try:

```
td.tags
{
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```